# How can i test main.ts in nestJs?

Tags: nestjs

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { RunnerModule } from './runner.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(RunnerModule);
  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();
```

So this is the main ts. I want to test it but i dont know how to test that app is listening on port 3000
mock the path

Answer (score 0):

there's nothing to test in that file.

Instead, you could write an integration test for `RunnerModule`, just like the docs shows for E2E tests.

I don't get why you want to test if the server is listening to some port since this piece of logic was not written by you, that is something that the framework should take care.

Comment: Sometimes, you have to cover the code with test because it is mandatory for some reasons that you can't control. Imagine, large company with CI/CD pipelines with a rule done for a DevOps saying "code for *ts must be > 70%". Even, if it doesn't make sense as you said (completely agree with you), however you can change  that

Comment: you can add main.ts to files ignored from coverage report in the jest config.

Answer (score 0):

If your `main.ts` looks like the following:

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import { NestExpressApplication } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import { AppModule } from 'app.module';
import { configureApp } from 'app.config';

export async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestExpressApplication>(AppModule);

  /**
   * All app configuration should be added to `configApp` for re-use within integration/e2e tests.
   */
  configureApp({ app });

  const configService = app.get(ConfigService);
  await app.listen(configService.get('APPLICATION_PORT', 3000), '0.0.0.0');
}
void bootstrap();
```

You can test this by doing the following. Also note that since there is a call to `bootstrap` your mocks may be called multiple times.

```
import { createMock } from '@golevelup/ts-jest';
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { NestExpressApplication } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import { configureApp } from 'app.config';
import { bootstrap } from 'main';

jest.mock('@nestjs/core', () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  default: jest.fn(),
  NestFactory: {
    create: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(createMock<NestExpressApplication>()),
  },
}));
jest.mock('app.module');
jest.mock('app.config');

describe('App Bootstrap', () => {
  it('it bootstraps and launches the application', async () => {
    await bootstrap();

    const factoryCreateSpy = jest.spyOn(NestFactory, 'create');

    expect(factoryCreateSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(configureApp).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a lot more logic in my `entry.ts` file so I needed a more inclusive approach. I adapted coler-j's answer a little bit and split up my entry point bootstrap and global config.

> My nest app is called `main-api` so much of the naming starts with `main-api*`

**src/main-api-entry.ts**

```js
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';

import { MainApiModule } from './main-api.module';
import { IMainAppConfig } from 'shared/types';
import { configureMainApiNestApp } from './main-api-bootstrap-config';

async function bootstrap () {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(MainApiModule, {
    cors: true,
    bufferLogs: true
  });

  /* call through to global config in separate file */
  configureMainApiNestApp(app);

  const configService = app.get<ConfigService<IMainAppConfig, true>>(ConfigService);

  await app.listen(configService.get('APP_PORT'));

  console.info('Starting app...', {
    apiBase: configService.get('API_BASE'),
    port: configService.get('APP_PORT'),
    isProd: configService.get('IS_PROD'),
    url: (await app.getUrl())?.replace('[::1]', 'localhost')
  });
}

bootstrap();
```

**src/main-api-bootstrap-config.ts**

```js
import * as cookieParser from 'cookie-parser';
import { INestApplication, ValidationPipe, VersioningType } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Application as ExpressApplication } from 'express';

/* app specific files */
import { appExceptionFactory, AllExceptionsFilter } from 'shared/errors';
import { GlobalAuthGuard } from 'shared/auth';

export function configureMainApiNestApp (
  app: INestApplication
) {
  const expressApp = app.getHttpAdapter() as any as ExpressApplication;

  app.useGlobalGuards(app.get(GlobalAuthGuard));

  /* validation errors get caught by this pipe */
  /* see: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/validation */
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({
    stopAtFirstError: false,
    transform: true,
    whitelist: true,
    exceptionFactory: appExceptionFactory
  }));
  app.useGlobalFilters(app.get(AllExceptionsFilter));

  /* general api stuff */
  expressApp.disable('x-powered-by');
  app.use(cookieParser());
  app.setGlobalPrefix('api');
  app.enableVersioning({
    type: VersioningType.URI,
    prefix: 'v',
    defaultVersion: '4'
  });

  return app;
}
```

#### In My Tests

**tests/e2e/app.e2e.test.ts**

```js
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { HttpStatus, INestApplication } from '@nestjs/common';
import * as request from 'supertest';
/* these import paths are project specific */
import { MainApiModule } from '../../src/main-api.module';
import { configureMainApiNestApp } from '../../src/main-api-bootstrap-config';


describe('MainApiModule (e2e)', () => {
  let app: INestApplication;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [MainApiModule]
    }).compile();

    app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
    /* configure global config for my test app instance */
    configureMainApiNestApp(app);

    await app.init();
  });

  it('GET /api/v4/test/auth', () => {
    return request(app.getHttpServer())
      /* `/api/v4` prefix and version is correct from global config */
      .get('/api/v4/test/auth')
      /* global auth is setup (this is an app specific endpoint) */
      .expect(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED); 
  });
});
```